# Country specific playlists in Spotify

Tags: spotify

First time when I used Spotify and created account, I was located in Austria. This location must have got stored in Spotify. Now even if I'm actually living in another country, I still get recommendations for playlist in German, with German language songs.

How can I change or reset location in Spotify?

I'm having this issue across all devices—from web player to the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

Go to: https://www.spotify.com/uk/accounts/profile/ (Or *Account* → *View account* → *Edit profile*)

There is the Country drop-down, where another one can be selected. The `/uk/` part in the URL is country code based on my current location. It may be different for you. Only my current new location and old locations were available. After changing to current country, the selection is no longer available.

More: https://support.spotify.com/uk/learn-more/faq/#!/article/How-can-I-change-my-country-setting

Answer (score 0):

One more thing I noticed that you may find interesting.

As you may have noticed, Spotify Premium has different price depending on your region. You may pay different price for the same service depending where you are located [(someone even made infographic about it)](http://mts.io/projects/spotify-pricing/).

And even though I am located in UK and my country is currently set to there, when I was signing up for Premium, I tried to use my card issued elsewhere. Spotify detects that and I **must** change my country or use different card.